# Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.(2589)

Tags: typescript

In the code below, inputs and outputs are chained together.  Each node in the chain only cares about its predecessor's `Output` and considers it as `Input`.  With the code below I assume typescript is building a really long type - hence the compiler slows down to being unusable - which ultimately results in `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.(2589)`.  In this simplified code it takes 6 nodes to hit that limit, however, in my actual code, it hits it already 2 nodes in.

I have a few related questions:

1. is there any solution to this problem? - I assume from [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34933) the answer is no.
2. can anyone suggest an alternative approach that may achieve something similar?
3. is it possible to flatten a type so that Typescript doesn't end up building really long, complex types?

```js
type LMerge<T1, T2> = {
  [k in keyof T1]: k extends keyof T2 ? T2[k] : T1[k]
}

type ChainNodePossibleGenerics = { Output?: unknown }

type ChainNodeGenerics = {
  Output: unknown
  Input: unknown
  Depth: unknown
}

type RecursionNext = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, never]

type CurrentDepth<Node extends ChainNodeGenerics> = Node['Depth'] extends number
  ? RecursionNext[Node['Depth']]
  : [Node['Depth']] extends [never]
  ? never
  : 0

type NextNode<
  Node extends ChainNodeGenerics,
  Child extends ChainNodePossibleGenerics,
  DefaultsApplied = LMerge<{ Input: Node['Output']; Output: unknown }, Child>,
  NormalisedChild extends ChainNodeGenerics = LMerge<ChainNodeGenerics, DefaultsApplied>,
  MergedType extends ChainNodeGenerics = LMerge<
    NormalisedChild,
    {
      Depth: CurrentDepth<Node>
    }
  >,
> = MergedType

type ChainNode<Node extends ChainNodeGenerics> = {
  <T extends ChainNodePossibleGenerics = {}, Child extends ChainNodeGenerics = NextNode<Node, T>>(
    asyncFn: any,
  ): ChainNode<Child>
  depth: Node['Depth']
  input: Node['Input']
  output: Node['Output']
}

/* ***** EXAMPLE USAGE *************** */

let cN0: ChainNode<LMerge<ChainNodeGenerics, { Output: 'stringI' }>>
// @ts-ignore
const cN1 = cN0<{ Output: 'A' }>('a')
const d = cN1.depth // 0
const cN1Input = cN1.input // 'stringI'
const cN1Output = cN1.output // 'A'

const cN2 = cN1<{ Output: 'B' }>('b')
const d2 = cN2.depth //  1
const cN2Input = cN2.input // 'A''
const cN2Output = cN2.output // 'B'

const cN3 = cN2<{ Output: 'C' }>('c')
const d3 = cN3.depth // 2
const cN3Input = cN3.input // 'B'
const cN3Output = cN3.output // 'C'

const cN4 = cN3<{ Output: 'D' }>('d')
const d4 = cN4.depth // 3
const cN4Input = cN4.input // 'C'
const cN4Output = cN4.output // 'D'

const cN5 = cN4<{ Output: 'E' }>('e')
const d5 = cN5.depth // 4
const cN5Input = cN5.input // 'D'
const cN5Output = cN5.output // 'E'

const cN6 = cN5<{ Output: 'F' }>('f') // Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.(2589)
const d6 = cN6.depth // any!!!!
const cN6Input = cN6.input // any
const cN6Output = cN6.output // any

const cN7 = cN6<{ Output: 'G' }>('g')
const d7 = cN7.depth // any!!!!
const cN7Input = cN7.input // any
const cN7Output = cN7.output // any
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=83&pc=1#code/PQKgBApgzgNglgOwC4FoAmcoEMBGMJgACSAngA7QDGATnGatPMsDlgiklCpQPYC2fCMjAhgAKFCRYiVBmx4CxclVr0UjGSzYdlUEeNIUwAGQCyEagHMIAHgAqARgA0YOwCYAfGAC8YAN5iYGAA2gDWYIhgoRAkPABmrg4AugBcUZAAHkhCaHrRsQnuYAD8rm5hSWBpjhViAL5iYoYEAMIAFliIAHI8aBAACjxQUHAKAOJCFnCUer5+YADyAK5IZCvFaUsIoQg8AO4IYA1NymDtnQg9fRMIUzM+-oGLK2tIm9u7B08Akgiv7zt9ggngARCD0NoAz7A47NMAAJQglCW1BGPEuECyD2CzjAbhcAGYXAAWFwAVhcADYXAB2FwADhcAE4XLcAG4WJKNOEtFHUIRIMEQmxXAiY7IIXJnDrdXoQG53KBeXyi4IAciFSDaasq4pyegQSz4OAsT1KiORqLg6K64uCqo14K1Oq5QTS9rl6s12qSuqy+pC7M5ZrAQeoTzSAAZuadbVlRTYnqLMhKpedZddJrQZk4nu04DA0CmA+nLnLBsNRvgFdmoLmgmC4lgljBOABBMhkeAQIu+MwWaw2ea-f5gB3LVYrHUAbmek7eYC2gIORxc+cLHnrY541D4WHgUB766LeslelLopr01mJnMVlsF7lV5zYEbzdbUA7XbgPc3Tzv1hoHYpynmmMplpmty1g8-b3omQRBD0u77pgR5tAWaBbkEAQIQh3ppLy1D8sg3oinKHhPEEDRBH+ypgABPbARQMZGI+fRkX0xZntKFyXlm150ThYD2FxYG8eWQwjOM-H3HMdRruhhaiee4F8VB14PHGSAJqKLh2B4HgABSUWAWBQCQCCUAAYggaRsCQW4AJQEapco2MeFFBH0EJpA63o6k8iCjg6I5Tq6YA8C8Ky+Z6aoTq8AXHJIIApSlYAAKIABptqY-TGOlYAAKoAMptmMBWpZVVWpfojT4EgYCUF0kYueJ7GwYObHyjJdb+HOo5qlASC0AgljfGqRwGRIwBEJwKBwJYuz8mIvAIENjVdA4DxNZGQ79dFYBqm2E11EZapYGqjkrei629htDgAHTeVqYDADN0aretTUOKFDW+N9D1BSsr0zYNw2IGNarXWtDXffFwP-ZtD2RfOIOHcdjSfbDXRuNtm17fDC5qgAQidZ04Jd0O3bjiNuE9TptGjYAOFT2NuL9eN00DDVvejapQ1jG1uITnPI1FPOg6TmM3djBKcwT4tpGqLRk4ZaqUJTgtoHLiMEvTEJo24rMbQSHO64DfzA7zJMCzLJsi+bKOvGjytQ8bTXEnjBIK-OSsgqrapoJrdtoJ7iPEvrL28wS7tdMSZsbRH3MuyrsfEg7idi6j1v+9LMMbWSePEj7A3pQHEDB-naCF4jZKR4zvPErHZIJ01dfJzntv523Gdt1nzvW2XedfV0lJ42SJcHWqVkB3El1o0xBCIENbBIHAWBr+iER6JilDQCMHIwCQYB9OCpmSmAZCSVWx+IHEiBwNkD2GW4ZL0kyV1a2PiOUvXaP2QAQiAQA2OlJW6jwtgPGa9lQG9wgU7K20CEAkGHtjGkeNKSTyJmMAOlhK63XQYjGkf9eaAOAbHGk4DiEdyQSgwWTUaRwOIQgiW58UFAA)

Comment: Yeah it's possible to "flatten a type" - and the answer is to never get there in the first place, through the use of [tail call optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71912809/18244921) for types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question in a slightly different way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73629302/how-to-improve-typescripts-performance-in-the-following-scenario) and it provided [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73629878/3091013)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to understand your code, but It really did not make much sense to me. So I tried to model an alternative `ChainNode` type purely based on the output types you showed in your question.

I don't really see a reason to use recursion in the first place. Each Node seems to only need to know the `Output` of the previous Node.

```
type Increment = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

type ChainNode<
  T extends { Output: any },
  O2 extends { Output: any } = T,
  I = -1
> = { 
  <O extends { Output: any }>(arg: any): 
    ChainNode<O2, O, I extends -1 
      ? 0 
      : Increment[I & keyof Increment]>
  depth: I
  input: T["Output"]
  output: O2["Output"]
}
```

It seems to produce the same types and does not run into the same issue.

```
let cN0: ChainNode<{ Output: 'stringI' }> = {} as any

const cN1 = cN0<{ Output: 'A' }>('a')

cN1.depth
//  ^? 0

cN1.input
//  ^? "stringI"

cN1.output
//  ^? "A"

const cN2 = cN1<{ Output: 'B' }>('b')

const d2 = cN2.depth 
//    ^? 1

const cN2Input = cN2.input 
//    ^? "A"

const cN2Output = cN2.output
//    ^? "B"

const cN3 = cN2<{ Output: 'C' }>('c')
const d3 = cN3.depth // 2
const cN3Input = cN3.input // 'B'
const cN3Output = cN3.output // 'C'

const cN4 = cN3<{ Output: 'D' }>('d')
const d4 = cN4.depth // 3
const cN4Input = cN4.input // 'C'
const cN4Output = cN4.output // 'D'

const cN5 = cN4<{ Output: 'E' }>('e')
const d5 = cN5.depth // 4
const cN5Input = cN5.input // 'D'
const cN5Output = cN5.output // 'E'

const cN6 = cN5<{ Output: 'F' }>('f') // works fine
const d6 = cN6.depth 
//    ^? 5  
const cN6Input = cN6.input 
//    ^? "E"
const cN6Output = cN6.output 
//    ^? "F"

const cN7 = cN6<{ Output: 'G' }>('g')
const d7 = cN7.depth 
//    ^? 6
const cN7Input = cN7.input
//    ^? "F"
const cN7Output = cN7.output
//    ^? "G"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Thanks, Tobias, I appreciate the time you've taken to prepare this answer.  The code in my question is already significantly simplified from my actual code, and you've simplified it even further.  Of course, simpler is better, so I'll see if I can simplify my actual code - although this is probably the 20th time I've rewritten it without success.

Comment: @TrevTheDev - I think it would be helpful if you could briefly describe what the code is supposed to represent and *why* you wrote it like that.