# Calculating the type as a generic vs. in the return of the type

Tags: typescript

Given these similar types:

```js
type Foo1<T> = (a:T)=>T
type Foo2<T, RT = (a:T)=>T> = RT
```

I've noticed that the approach used in `Foo2`, where the type is included as a calculated generic, is sometimes preferable as it:

- can improve typescript performance, and
- it can [destructure the returned type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=42&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAjAHgCoD4oF4oG8CGAXFKgL4BQoksCATGlgM7ABOAlgHYDmmOAFAEos6eEjTpK4aKIDM2GnFpQA9MqiDsmUSmbtuEydQBC+FilQAaKACVU8gsTK8bqQ9BMt6qJq05crtvKCwh7m6M62blAecjgeSqrqApp4UFBEULp+ANxQpEA) in the IDE - which is sometimes useful.

I've discovered this through trial and error, but I'd really like to understand how these types are different and when one should be preferred over the other.  I'm using `Foo2`'s approach by default now as it just seems to work better and avoids some downstream issues.

Can anyone explain the differences and similarities?

Comment: Can you back up "can improve TypeScript performance?" with anything? Benchmarks? GitHub issues? Articles? Otherwise, it seems like a matter of preference of which to use...

Comment: @caTS: I ran into a [performance problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73697066/3091013) and one solution was as per this question.  In recursive types, this approach is sometimes more performant.