# "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite" only within Promise.all

Tags: typescript, recursion, typescript-generics

I am working on a strongly typed localisation system and I am encountering a typescript error when using `Promise.all` to retrieve multiple translations generic functions asynchronously.

In this [bare minimal reproduction playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFpK6dv4YpSBQJSgJYEYAcA7YAFwE8AHTfAcwGcA6AEzqJrTGQ86+7hRQYCmAYwA2AQwBOA0PjEBbATTJih0gJJ58oAN4oMlIgIkAzFdIAqEsfhriimAPY2dAXxRu2EHt5+-InrE1ickVmVnQ-SKjUFFIyaQApB0oAHgBlbAAaUDSAJgA+UABeHOxQAQAPQ3wGGlAaIglKKj1QAH4c3PKqgRq6hqbqVowOgAMAEm0MlzpJvJdR4dAALlLW1fwBADcjAG4+SrIHCSJQOIsrGztHGwARTCF7J0kSYtANAjpLa1sxJ5t9ihDsdTudQN8rn8BAA5eSKZSqN4AUSqVkeKQA1gISA5jODLr9-jR7o8bi9sgNmvlAcCTmcQviftcnDQAAp-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-Egeyy51IKrTCtCEqgNZMpyvZjKQkSJL-OS9S9lQLmrEKnpiilaXonZCoRX8X65WSEgkElKqZBGxWPpqFQ6nqNqGq8in1s6-UIUhw1GhGDYabVOUPHlTUtXRbYMR2IYSGGEZRoF8bmRIKbMRmWbRkYnV5sIZElsZ5aVtWd51iwj5NgSkXEnNjXNdCKpLW5Aadt2m2gAOQ6juO7SPhpM6TNCLjLJMamaYR67roeW47nuB5HiehHnvdV43log1EODnrPsk+ApOKy3uUxYxQzDcMLqss7Q8sozvs9dUsrFXIpDN9Vvc8C2fT6AGncBoEjuBkHQZdcEcfawkoWhy6YdhuH4dQ2PEaRRaXWW1EaRgT1MpzdwC7IQtfS29HU4VElSV5CZcTxAh8aAgkOqJBEJpJbGO1usmu-Jd1KVmzP03OCxi9pulXvphma8ZpmGysu2tC4Vmoul1UORzs2koLH2tQVzkqvsGeVbZ8q5yb+fzSQTmqjbAaUJ5HG+R0-m7YCwAAFS93ovdZYS0jGAOBdaCOK5CByxqGmSIGvCoqiGleMhwkoZh46AxiYEWpySFQrG9EToC98AQIhSC9LxMPdgCLzsIKJviJUwGM0whvCLSAmA6CLvmwGACl5E-eEW8351A-qAl+AglgdCgV-MwYZzDQO-oBDSxtsoCFuAIUw2oRBEB7v3Qed8oQ73Hv8M+vdlYYSwv3dez9v7ZGguLUcdQUYnn3I8OOA08TLh3CBEhYgthiEwOIdGJdmhri0LhEQDCwGqHoIPC+tJQQMg-jgvBBC3i82DEQQsWgSjtWQq0GgmDPwsmiiIbmrBKLFEKOYPRBiiEDzPqQww5D8ATyoTQ+hshGFmGYQfECbCNz1GMpeJwZZsbiyvCIsRu59wkMmilfhoAqCXS0P4hRAg6DKMvqFNRt8EEBNUMg1B4CfqQLzp-UpAgBSgB5F6JxEhDGSKGPkExGAzHuK-DY3med+YTxeMKFBiDVDF0aNqepmQUB2KKA4lp+Ae7sGiGs9Z4AAg4AIMAasRBzBhE8Bs45kQDhXzCgyAA4gIfZOiQHjOkBA9xtScnMT-rgygAgGBvHeQAr5-IumgFAkIXCAg2irE2q0bJMDwXggqaoOZ9jQCsgkA4KCJ4Bm1wfmMupAEVnpJueYLABp9wKHwEQU2WAbyPG1LI14UhwCqK+TvVFxFNhVHANKLBQLMAmisE1Ap18uw2FOHsolJRkLIXmYUbQLg7HXlANc-Z+KTmqu8FsklNoT5eUMA0cIqy1WGuQHwYVDRQBmhoE4AAYmIgQ7JqwAAk0XSAShgewRB9yrDTE6hQ4EqwCDTO4QEprTgWutba+1Ah+JcSwm8Uq7rPWgDTNG1WfrqxplmRgBQFKSpLGyV6-iiYGjMuzWIeRgaMAuEzfqfqJU3AuHxWIbUVAyWnG2Vkh5EpDAmDMKwQQohJDSGhd-d4mgdCtAMEYUwiI+YsnHRpDCChVjnAVGG-ANr9yRp9QIfYGldyq2XSEVdlr10Rv9SmrCu7QD1rOYUvGJAvGeO8TQLs8QpXjtaCGs4263hiBwiwsVyE0y9AzUmxdAbKJXvQJ6AAem0T9LJQQXtOCUP9ojRWEqAyB7IaZ91YTTJB1o0GMBwYQyK0A4HzDQX3G8Ig26gMJog1BsAsH4MYC-XhogABZG5YhQG0eQ0B0tdBskEeYxpUjRGwBpKMKiji64zxSDI2a4UdHnXBjkA4Qw2QiDIY01pgQvpUP-tOCitFq5cmyOQsKJYgHgP4FA2mcDBHq0YDs9hpNnGXOtBVIRlwQA) you can see the error at line `131`, here below you can see the same code.

The usage of the same function `getT` does not give errors when used "singularly" outside of `Promise.all`.
Do you know why this happens and how to work around it?

*thanks in advance*

```js
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  i18n/typings.d.ts
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

declare namespace I18n {
  interface Translations {}
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  i18n/types.ts
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Join<S1, S2> = S1 extends string
  ? S2 extends string
    ? `${S1}.${S2}`
    : S1
  : never;

export type TranslationsDictionary = I18n.Translations;

export type TranslateNamespace = Extract<keyof TranslationsDictionary, string>;

export type TranslationsPaths<
  T
> = {
  [K in Extract<keyof T, string>]:
    // exclude empty objects, empty arrays, empty strings
    T[K] extends Record<string, never> | never[] | "" ? never
    // recursively manage objects
    : T[K] extends Record<string, unknown> ? 
      | `${K}` // this is to be able to use the object as an object
      | Join<K, TranslationsPaths<T[K]>>
    // allow primitives or arrays (without walking them recursively)
    : T[K] extends string | number | boolean | Array<string | number | boolean | object> ? `${K}`
    // exclude anything else
    : never;
}[Extract<keyof T, string>] extends infer O ? O : never;

export type TranslationsAllPaths = {
  [N in Extract<keyof TranslationsDictionary, string>]: {
    [K in Extract<keyof TranslationsDictionary[N],string>]:
      // exclude empty objects, empty arrays, empty strings
      TranslationsDictionary[N][K] extends Record<string, never> | never[] | "" ? never
      // recursively manage objects
      : TranslationsDictionary[N][K] extends Record<string, unknown> ?
          | `${N}:${K}` // this is to be able to use the object as an object
          | Join<K extends string ? `${N}:${K}` : `${N}:`, TranslationsPaths<TranslationsDictionary[N][K]>>
      // allow primitives or arrays (without walking them recursively)
      : TranslationsDictionary[N][K] extends string | number | boolean | Array<string | number | boolean | object> ? `${N}:${K}`
      // exclude anything else
      : never
  }[Extract<keyof TranslationsDictionary[N], string>];
}[Extract<keyof TranslationsDictionary, string>] extends infer O ? O : never;

/**
 * Translate function which optionally accept a namespace as first argument
 */
export type Translate<TNamespace extends TranslateNamespace | undefined> =
  TNamespace extends TranslateNamespace
    ? TranslateNamespaced<TNamespace>
    : TranslateDefault;

/**
 * Translate function **without** namespace, it allows to select any of the all
 * available strings in all namespaces.
 */
export type TranslateDefault = <TReturn = string>(
  s: TranslationsAllPaths
) => TReturn;

/**
 * Translate function **with** namespace, it allows to select only the all available
 * strings in the given namespace.
 */
export type TranslateNamespaced<TNamespace extends TranslateNamespace> = <
  TReturn = string
>(
  s: TranslationsPaths<TranslationsDictionary[TNamespace], true>,
) => TReturn;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  i18n/getT.ts
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

export type GetT = <
  TNamespace extends TranslateNamespace | undefined = undefined
>(
  locale?: string,
  namespace?: TNamespace
) => Promise<Translate<TNamespace>>;

// getT implementation is actually re-exported from next-translate library
export const getT = (() => {}) as GetT;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  implementer tests
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

const jsonFilePageHome = {
  title: "Home page"
};

const jsonFilePageAbout = {
  title: "About page",
  meta: {
    name: "A nested meta name"
  },
  empty: {}
};

// augment i18n namespace interfaces
declare namespace I18n {
  interface Translations {
    home: typeof jsonFilePageHome;
    about: typeof jsonFilePageAbout;
  }
}

export async function scope() {

  const tHome = await getT("en", "home");
  //    ^?
  const tAbout = await getT("en", "about");
  //    ^?
  const homeTitle = tHome("title");
  //    ^?
  const aboutMetaName = tAbout("meta.name");
  //    ^?

  // the error is here
  const [tHomeRemote, tAboutRemote] = await Promise.all([
    getT("en", "home"),
    getT("en", "about"),
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include your [mre] as plaintext and not just as an external IDE link (or I can do it if you don't mind).

Comment: Should I just copy paste all the code here @jcalz?

Comment: Yes, assuming it fits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73629302/how-to-improve-typescripts-performance-in-the-following-scenario) I've managed to fix it by adding at the end of the recursive type  `extends infer O ? O : never;` as stated in the answer linked above this

> compute the result and store it in an object

[here is the playground with the working solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFpK6dv4YpSBQJSgJYEYAcA7YAFwE8AHTfAcwGcA6AEzqJrTGQ86+7hRQYCmAYwA2AQwBOA0PjEBbATTJih0gJJ58oAN4oMlIgIkAzFdIAqEsfhriimAPY2dAXxRu2EHt5+-InrE1ickVmVnQ-SKjUFFIyaQApB0oAHgBlbAAaUDSAJgA+UABeHOxQAQAPQ3wGGlAaIglKKj1QAH4c3PKqgRq6hqbqVowOgAMAEm0MlzpJvJdR4dAALlLW1fwBADcjAG4+SrIHCSJQOIsrGztHGwARTCF7J0kSYtANAjpLa1sxJ5t9ihDsdTudQN8rn8BAA5eSKZSqN4AUSqVkeKQA1gISA5jODLr9-jR7o8bi9sgNmvlAcCTmcQviftcnDQAAp-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-OS9S9lQemrEKnpin5AXohpCpOX8X7hWSEgkD5KqZBGsWPpqFQ6nqNqGq8taWk6+qVQhDq1RVRoRg2QnpWFDwRTleU4W2eEdiGEhhhGUbWfGikSCmhEZlm0ZGMVebCIWxaluWlbVnedYsI+TYEs5xJddluXQiqfUGQGnbdqNoADkOo68W0j5CTOkzQi4yyTAJwlnCua51IeW47nuB5Hiev3nttV43lo1UPkJCOES++ApOK-WGQRYxvR9X0Lqss7vcsozvvtGUsu5XIpB1mVHc8PWnT6AGLcBoEjuBkHQSWijGmR9qMch7NoZzsG7SFn4slldMnWdLa4Rj0VsRxJkJhRVECDRoD0Q6zEyQm7EkcrW7cerj2gATONzgszOieJV6SdJ1CyfJiNWTmGAuCpqKBalWmk51pJS3lOmqvsHvJep8q+0yZN3LTsg5cH1B6XLAaUMZZHmR0lmTbZ9mggyHUCFTsIKEoZgp3Uhcl-C5cJgOgjGJQAgMAKvLV2XiLowGVdwh3AhLB0PelwizfF73I+AUJe3R4YtwCKY2oiEQgLAAAVKveir2LdjSMYA4B1o68jtBHIONqRDrzI49mNk0Es6OAObie+6PHbVV4suO4gZvV5bGImDiBBlFFia4tBiBAlfYeZh6Cb2AECOyIJ6TxG3lCOeC8l5vCpsGIghYtAlEKgAClaDQaeoUvyuREBTVgABKYohRzDYNwSvdeP9C6gD3vgA+oAj4n0vrIKBqhb6nHAazR+9QBAv1OE4MsEMWa-3-oA-cP9Wp+U-qAKgXMtD8JrqoOgsD4F5yQRcGeMJr6qDDOYduI8K4oMMFYswApQA8i9IwiQeDgHNH5EQjAJDbFfioVTP2NMD4vGFJYsxAh-yZBQLQoo9DXH4BXuwaIKTUngACDgAgwBqxEHMGETwaTCmRAOAghyDIADiAhcmYLbhEmxQ8dHSDrjUeeTcGBvHrq0zYDAvGtFAkIcBAg2irFGq0bRfdhngnsaoGJdDQCsgkA4KCJ5AkmLHgIgQAEknqKqeYLABp9wKHwEQGOWAbyPG1CI14UhwC0kMO04wiy5CJiqOAaUoVpAiEwCaKwOUDGIK7DYU4OS9klAIQQ2JhRtAuFodeUAlTcnbKKci7wGSDk2l6IYMihgGjhGSSiglyA+CAoaKAM0NAnAADEAECHZNWAAEks6QXkMD2CIPuVYaZGUKHAlWAQaZ3CAhJacclVKaV0oELRCi583jxTZRy0AaYpVn1OMoasaZokYAUCcuKSxtGctoomBozdQDarEJA-lrQXCatAF8hoqxhRLDTGIDVTqTQCowPlVozUSBxWtd6l0AAZVcRAHUqkFXwdAYhtRUCOacTJWi6kGCMKYVQrBBCiEkNIcZ1iPhaHismkw5dqYsh0EsU+ChVjnAVKK-A1L9wSu5QIfYQldwqqrSEGtFK63ir5cq8+LbQBuA8Hc6GJBOHsP3v8eoXZ4gQrLa0YVZwm1vDECOf+wLdkELTL0DViqK38uoYO9AnoAB6T0MBLqIP204JQ10bp2bk7du7sjOulUQNMR7WgnowOexdLJTjCiIMGOQDhDDZCIE2kDYGBAQZvdBwwvo73rrvgspZq4BB0BEQQx1QkQXPvwJ+m1GB8M7sI6+g9RGlikZfYqtt58qOeq-f+oFoApCgcMGkaKnky2tqrU27d8rD3Ea3FWm926zV0G0Yxz0Qgq0IYENug9ywhMyYwAweTNoYPbvo6GyT0nqEiYEPxplCnBPQX3Gp9hYn31mbTKpwz1GbMqrs2aqzHJnPn1c1UsQUm4RWcwJ5og267Ufsc0JdAAABFgty7KWluYheCPqGqMX6KfRe7ThynG3LdE8u4lFCREEF59QaQ1WaizFw48WjCLLIsluGLB6jpZEJlsDQNcvqxBksOQxWd0uhk8OlAQA)

Comment: I've only managed to find the right SO link after I posted the question, the SO `Related` column was of great help!